# Microsoft Store not opening; can't reinstall [0x80073CF6, 0x80073CFC]

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store, microsoft-store

Using Windows 10 Home, 64bit, version 21H1 (now updated to 21H2; same issue), OS build: 19043.1706.
I have tried many things but none of them work

1. Microsoft Store doesn't even appear in Settings>Apps[image]
2. `WSReset.exe`, `wsreset` multiple times via Start>Run and restarted
3. Ran `sfc /scannow` as an administrator
4. Ran various `DISM` scan and repair, restore commands as an administrator
5. Used *Tweaking.com - Windows Repair* tool `27.01 Repair Windows App Store` and `27.02 Repair Windows app store (completely reset app store)`, restarted afterwards
6. Used AppxBundle file to install an app manually through powershell and by double-clicking on file, this was the error I was getting:

> App installation failed with error message: Deployment Add operation
> with target volume C: on Package
> Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2019.19041.20110.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
> from:
> (Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2019.19041.20110.0_neutral___8wekyb3d8bbwe.AppxBundle)
> failed with error 0x8000FFFF. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
> deployment issues. (0x8000ffff)

[image]

7. Used various powershell command to re-register, reinstall Microsoft Store app. Errors again:

> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package
> could not be registered. error 0x80073CFC: While processing the
> request, the system failed to register the windows.integrityExtension
> extension due to the following error: The application cannot be
> started. Try reinstalling the application to fix the problem. . NOTE:
> For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
> 3ad2af6f-6d46-0004-c3c5-d23a466dd801 in the Event Log or use the
> command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID
> 3ad2af6f-6d46-0004-c3c5-d23a466dd801 At line:1 char:1
>
> - Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Win ...
> - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ppxManifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId: DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

...Nothing of this has worked.

Please don't tell me I have to completely reinstall and reset Windows because of this minor problem. I've heard it enough on Microsoft forums (Microsoft Community) as the first answer and solution to everything...

Comment: Make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Account and see if Store and Photos work.

Comment: Are you running Professional or Home? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.Due to the fact Windows Store is not in the WinSxS directory that likely will ultimately be the solution.  The good news you can install the same version and keep all your personal files. If I were to guess you are either running an edition of Windows that purposefully does not have the Windows Store installed or your System Administrator removed it purposefully permanently for all users. A well know tool, used to “increase privacy” on Windows 10, can also remove Windows Store applications for all users.

Comment: Created it. Tried opening Microsoft Store, it quickly opened and closed, nothing loaded, simply the logo of the store and app  immediately quit. I don't have photos app on neither accounts, I had uninstalled it some time ago. @Ramhound I have used various privacy tools in the past but Store app has always worked, I haven't used a privacy tool maybe in 3 months, but store app stopped working a month or so ago, simply at random. Since 2015, Store app has always stopped working after some time, it seems almost like a feature of UWP apps...

Comment: I think your user profile is damaged and the easiest (not the only) way is to back up and reinstall Windows, make your existing profile and recover your data and apps.

Comment: @computeruser1 - If you did anything to the WindowsApps directory then your only solution is to perform a repair install with a 21H1 ISO. Those privacy tools are most definitely the source of your issues. Windows Store itself is a UWP application by the way.

Comment: I wonder if this problem is related to the issues mentioned in this Bleeping Computer news article from a day or two ago? If so it appears that there is a new patch. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/emergency-windows-10-updates-fix-microsoft-store-app-issues/

Comment: @computeruser1 - Try installing [KB5015020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-19-2022-kb5015020-os-builds-19042-1708-out-of-band-9b5bd38a-ab3c-4ada-96b0-b754134fcd2a) and update your question . The article that has been linked is most definitely (or highest probability) related to your Windows Store issues.

Comment: @Ramhound, I installed it, but didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced these same errors (0x80073CF3, 0x80073CF6, 0x80073CFC, Purgecaches) the other day, and it took few hours to understand how to fix it.

**TL;DR** - for me the issue was incorrect dependency version of VCLibs in AppManifest for Windows Store. Setting it to correct version made everything work.

I faced this issues when trying to install WSL2, after that failed with uninformative errors I followed the advices and made wsreset and that is where all began.
General idea across the net is to perform a bunch of general purpose checks like *wsreset*, *sfc*, *dism*, reinstall via powershell and so on. Nothing helped on its own (I not so crazy to reinstall Windows).

After trying everything I started to dig deeper and finally found the issue: AppManifest.xml for WindowsStore has VCLib dependency version 14.0.30704.0, which was missing in WindowsApps folder. Fortunately, other version of VCLibs was present.
[image]

So, if the symptoms are that you Windows Store is opening and instantly closing, or showing Purgecaches error, or do nothing, you can try to fix it my way.
In case Windows Store missing, suprisingly working fix for it is to download XBox from website and install it with option to install Windows Store. It helped to restore Windows Store files, but didn't fixed errors (at least for me).

So in case you're going to fix dependencies, you need:

1. Try XBox fix above first, it may help. DO NOT START start with Remove-AppxPackage/Add-AppxPackage and other potentially destructive things.
2. Open AppManifest.xml for Windows Store (*Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_22311.1401.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml*). Check which version of VCLib dependency listed.
3. Go to WindowsApps folder and check if version from #3 is present. If it is, then the fix is not relevant unfortunately. If it's not, but other version is here, then the actual fix starts. If there are no VCLib, try XBox fix first.
4. TAKE BACKUP of Windows Store apps in case you messed up something.
5. Take ownership of AppManifest.xml and Windows Store folder.

   takeown /f Microsoft.WindowsStore_22310.1401.8.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
   icacls Microsoft.WindowsStore_22310.1401.8.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe /grant {YourUserName}:F
   takeown /f .\AppxManifest.xml
   icacls .\AppxManifest.xml /grant {YourUserName}:F
6. Most probable you won't able to directly edit and save AppManifest.xml after that (I wasn't) but it allows to copy-paste folder, so I copied whole Windows Store folder to other location, edited it there, and then copied back to WindowsApps, substituting files with my edited version.
7. Open your copy of AppManifest.xml, and change version of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 and Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop to what is present in your WindowsApps folder.
8. Copy folder with AppManifest.xml back to WindowsApps.
9. Optionally reload PC, althoug I didn't.
10. Run Windows Store.

For me after this it launched, and performed self update and restored correct version of VCLib. If it's not, you may try Remove-AppxPackage/Add-AppxPackage now to restore it.

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.WindowsStore | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppXPackage Microsoft.WindowsStore -AllUsers -Verbose | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -Verbose -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```